# How to achieve multi tenancy?

Tags: architecture, cloud, multi-tenant

I am new to cloud-computing. And while learning basic concepts got stuck with with- How design a system in which a single instance of a software (SaaS) can be used by multiple user at same time?

I understand what does it mean by multi-tenant, but could not get meaning of how to design or how to achieve that. i.e. If i have written simple program in java (suppose) and i want to make it multi-tenant, then what changes and/or configuration needed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience in working with creation / Migration of Apps to be multi-tenant aware,  the following are the typically followed steps. We can consider the conversion of an CRM [Customer Modules]

**Database Changes**

> - Add tenant id for each core business data tables [Customer, Tickets, Support, Contacts etc..]
> - group existing company data into different customers, this is a bit painful task, but can be done by mapping your existing customers as
>     tenant's and then doing the corresponding tenantid updates in the core
>     tables.
> - Partitions, if required like tenant1 may belong to partition 1 [USA] and some other tenants in Singapore may be put in a partition in
>     Asia, are to be setup and the data moved
> - Custom setting data per customer to be grouped as tenant's custom settings and stored in your core metadata database. This also includes
>     the white labeling stuff too.
> - Customer specific custom fields or extended data should be stored in a database with the appropriate tenant id values

**Application changes**

> - Establish a context for a tenant before and after login, before login to identify the mode in which the tenant wants his users to
>     login [one tenant wants AD and the other may need Google etc...]
> - Always isolate the data accessed by using some base filter that intercepts each query and ensures the integrity of the tenant's data
> - Manage the various partitions of the data for each tenant
> - Set up the code to accommodate the white labeling stuff that was stored in the db
> - Make changes in the services to ensure that the services contain the custom specific business rules / logic called in whenever
>     required.

The more complex the features that you wanted to, we would have more to discuss upon. Please share any specific features that you would to focus on so that it can be discussed in detail.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Multi tenancy is pretty wide term.

Most simplistically, you need to take care of

1. Creating accounts for users and making sure that the users can see ONLY their own data.
2. Create concept of groups/accounts. An account has multiple users. Someone in the account is admin etc.
3. Make sure that activities of one set of users cannot impact another set of users. e.g. one user should not be able to monopolize all the resources available to your application. You achieve this depending on your situation. Let's say a video streaming site; you put controls in place so that one user does not launch 1000 streams thus affecting services to other users.

As you can see above, much of the above is NOT limited to multi tenancy.

Comment: Thank you Amit for your point of view. Really appreciate for your time.

Comment: Lets us see if somebody else can share his/her point of view.